# Solving for zero using differentiation

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

I need help finding the min and max to the equation $y'= 4.9385 \cos(0.017(x-80)).$ I've tried this by making $y' = 0$ and tried to solve for $x$ but I don't understand how to do it.
So, can someone please help find the min and max for $0 = 4.9385 \cos(0.017(x-80))$ ?

Comment: Are you looking for the min of $y'$ or $y$?

Comment: If you have $y=f(x)$ then the min/max of $y$ is found by $y'=0$. Is this what you are trying to achieve? The post mentions the min/max of $y'$ which is confusing us.

Comment: yes sorry i'm looking for the min/max of y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the equation:

$$ y = A \sin( \kappa\, (x-a) ) $$

The min max of $y$ is $$ y' = A \kappa \cos(\kappa\, (x-a) ) =0$$

This is solved by $\cos(\kappa\, (x-a) )=0$ or

$$ \kappa\, (x-a)  = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi $$

Comment: ok question in the solved part what does the k and a values mean is it like the period the phase shift or something like that?

Comment: $\kappa$ is frequency in [rad/s], $a$ is phase shift in [rad] and $A$ the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

The min/max of $y$ is when $y'$ is 0. We solve this equation to find the min/max: $4.9385 \cos(0.017(x-80))=0 \implies 0.017(x-80)=90\text{ or }270\implies x = \frac{91360}{17}, \frac{271360}{17}$. The min and max are when $x = \frac{91360}{17}, \frac{271360}{17}$.

Comment: +1 Though I would edit the post so that instead of saying "90, 270" you say "90 or 270". You had me confused for a while thinking you meant 90 _thousand_ 270.

Comment: Yeah. I was very rushed when making this post and did not have time to thoroughly proof-read this post. Sorry.